While running Playwright on Selenium Grid, the file is downloaded in node machine but not showing in Selenium Grid session GET request
I am working on file downloading functionality with Playwright and Selenium Grid (in Java). Through Selenium Grid VNC, I see that the file is downloaded on my node machine.
Now I want to move the file from the node machine to the host machine so that I can verify the contents of the file.
So I am running GET API request
http://localhost:4444/session/454edbcffd9f9d5fc96aa1d04f240ba0/se/files
In API response, I don't see the downloaded file. I see the below response.
API Response
{"value":{"names":[]}}

What am I missing here, and how can I get the file?
// 1. Set the SELENIUM_REMOTE_URL capability
capabilities.put("SELENIUM_REMOTE_URL", "<GridURL>");

// 2. Set the se:downloadsEnabled capability
JsonObject capabilities = new JsonObject();
capabilities.addProperty("se:downloadsEnabled", "true");
env.put("SELENIUM_REMOTE_CAPABILITIES", capabilities.toString());

// 3. Pass capability in Playwright options;
Playwright.CreateOptions options = new Playwright.CreateOptions();
options.setEnv(capabilities);

// 4. Start Playwright with option
playwright = Playwright.create(options);

// 5. Code to Navigate to page and perform download...

What I Tried:
Referring the a user comment in this Issue in GitHub:

Without ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY_W3C, GET would return empty array of file

I tried possible ways to pass this Chrome capability in Playwright, but I didn't find any way to do this.
Useful docs:

Selenium Grid Documentation about GET Session API
Playwright Integration with Selenium Grid


I faced the same issue very recently when we tried using Playwright with Selenium Grid Managed Download feature.
We can call this a limitation of Playwright implementation as on date.
I got it working by using Raw CDP commands to intercept the Download to test runner machine

Start a new CDPSession Playwright Session
setDownloadBehavior via Playwright CDP Commands to a valid directory on Selenium Browser Node
Fetch.enable CDP commands
Fetch.requestPaused CDP command
Fetch.takeResponseBodyAsStream

The sample working code is available at https://github.com/amardeep2006/selenium-grid-experiments/blob/main/playwright/tests/
This code is not perfect and will need polishing but works and you can enhance it based on need.IT has samples for both streaming and non streaming download.
I have coded this based on suggestions and help I got from this thread on Playwrigt Github repo. https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/15999
I had also raised a feature request by Playwright maintainers rejected it
https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/32554
Let's hope it gets solved/becomes easy when Playwright starts supporting BiDi protocol completely.
Reference to Playwright and CDP APIs used :

https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-cdpsession
https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page/#method-setDownloadBehavior
https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Fetch/#method-enable
https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Fetch/#event-requestPaused
https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Fetch/#method-takeResponseBodyAsStream
https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/IO/#method-read

